# How can I make a bunch of horizontal divs responsive to the screen?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am displaying a number of boxes on the screen. These refer to containers of 2 sizes.

On a mobile screen, I want the boxes to reduce in size when the screen horizontal width is too small - **keeping the same aspect ratio**. How do I accomplish this? I don't know much about flexboxes to do this.

```css
html {
  font-family: verdana
}
.Container {
  white-space:nowrap;
  display:inline-block;
}
.Bx {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 2.0em;
  width: 5em;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  margin: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #f7e0f7;
}

.B4 {
  width: 10em;
  background-color: #e0f7ff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Box Test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <b>Box Test</b><br><br> Boxes should shrink <u>maintaining their aspect ratio</u>.<br><br> These boxes should shrink when the longest row cannot fit in the screen horizontally<br>
  <div class="Container">
    R1 <div class="Bx"></div><div class="Bx"></div><div class="Bx"></div><div class="Bx"></div><div class="Bx"></div><br>
    R2 <div class="Bx"></div><div class="Bx"></div><div class="Bx"></div><div class="Bx"></div><div class="Bx"></div><br>
    R3 <div class="Bx B4"></div><div class="Bx"></div><div class="Bx"></div><div class="Bx B4"></div><div class="Bx"></div><br>
    R4 <div class="Bx"></div><div class="Bx"></div></div><br>
    R5 <div class="Bx"></div><div class="Bx B4"></div><div class="Bx"></div><div class="Bx"></div><br>
    R6 <div class="Bx B4"></div><div class="Bx"></div><div class="Bx"></div><br>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Sounds like it is time to learn about responsive design.

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS @media queries with `aspect-ratio`

For example (taken from the mdn webpage below):

```
@media (aspect-ratio: 1/1) {
  div {
    background: #f9a; /* red */
  }
```

For further info, please refer to the mdn webpage
[aspect-ratio info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/aspect-ratio)